# Trouble starting Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm having trouble just starting selenium grid Hub. I'm using the following command:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub

And I get the following message:
Jul 25, 2012 1:26:26 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server

...but it never gets past that, just hangs. :4444 is unresponsive.

My questions are:
1. Is this even the correct way to start the hub? I've seen conflicting information on the internet, and even Selenium HQ is sometimes out of date. 
2. Is there a place where I might see some logging output as to what is crashing?

Thanks so much!

Comment: P.S. I only downloaded that one jar and am trying to run it as a command line app. I've seen information on the web that that is the correct way to do it, I've also seen people that have an entire directory structure around selenium grid: http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/download.html ... although it seems outdated to me.

Comment: You can try launching with logs on. Usually debug commands are written in log. java -jar selenium-server.jar -log pathtologfile/logfilename. What version of java are you having in your machine?

Comment: I've tried with java 1.6 and 1.7 ... I tried using the -log option, and sure enough it created a logfile, but alas it was empty :( ... it didn't get far enough to write anything in the log.

Comment: The [Grid2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) documentation still works for me.
Have you tried the -port option and used a different port.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...i've verified port 4444 is open, and I've tried with different ports to on avail...same thing :(

Comment: What happens when you start it without the parameter -role hub? same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As VolkerK said- [This](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) is the correct way to do it.

Worked perfectly for me.

Got further questions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and confirmation that it is indeed the correct way to start the hub. However it still hangs on "Launching a selenium grid server", and no service is actually started, and localhost:4444 is unresponsive. I wish it would at least print some sort of log or diagnostic information. I'm not positive it can run on RedHat 6.2. It DOES work like a champ on my other machine running RedHat 3.

Comment: please add this comments information to the question or delete it and start a new one like "Does selenium grid work on RedHat 6.2".. this might help